# Change image according to a condition

Tags: php, html

I have a condition according to which I want to display two different images.

**Code Involved :**

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count="<?php echo "". $row['SlackerTotal'] .""?>">
<div class="badgesize">
<a href="#"><img src="img/66.png" alt="" class="badge-img"></a>
</div>
</span>
```

I have a **data-count** value which I am going to echo from the DB.

Now what I am trying to do here is that if the value of data count is less than or equal to 0, then one image will be be displayed in the image tag.Else a different image will be displayed.

Kindly help,how can I do so ?

Comment: alert : a div within span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use `IF condition` Note : And take a look in  A.J mentioned comment about span

```
    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x has-badge" data-count="<?php echo "". $row['SlackerTotal'] .""?>"></span>
    <div class="badgesize">
    <?php
     if($row['SlackerTotal']<=0)
     {
     ?>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/66.png" alt="" class="badge-img"></a>
     <?php

     }
     else
     {

     ?>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/67.png" alt="" class="badge-img"></a>

    <?php 
     }
     ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice, I used jQuery in my answer but this way it looks easy and maintainable

Comment: he get $row['SlackerTotal'] value  from server side so we just manipulate it on server side. so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for data-count attribute value and depending on it set the src value of the image tag.

Example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $parent = $('.fa-stack.fa-5x.has-badge');
  var $img = $('img.badge-img');
  if($parent.data('count') > 0 ) {
    $img.attr('src','image path for more than 0');
  } else {
    $img.attr('src','image path for less than 0');
  }
})
```

Note: Code is not tested

Answer (score 1):

You have to use if-else condition to resolve this problem

can use as :

```
if($row['SlackerTotal'] <= 0) {
     //your image, what you want to display
  <div class="badgesize">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="img/66.png" alt="" class="badge-img">
   </a>
  </div>
 } else {
    //put your image, what you want to display in else condition
  <div class="badgesize">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="image_path" alt="" class="badge-img">
   </a>
  </div>
 }
```